# Inserting #ifdef with git (like diff -D)

Tags: git, diff

I modified some code of one my project due to the introduction of breaking change in the API of one of its dependency (actually the Haskell compiler). The project needs to stay compatible with the both the old and the new version so the commonly accepted solution is to use `#ifdef`. The question is there a way using git to generate those ifdef for me ?

For example, the actual code is (the state of the file within the current commit).

```
do something
```

I've modified it to work with the new version of the compiler (not commited yet)

```
do something else
```

What I need to commit is

```
#ifdef NEW_COMPILER
do something else
#else
do something 
#endif
```

The `diff` command with `-DNEW_COMPILER` would generate such a file, but it require some files manipulation. I was wondering if there was a git way to do it easily, or any tool which could help doing so.

Comment: Git does not write code.

Comment: I'm not asking git to write code but only to generate a sort of patch